# Pandas: Parsing dates in different columns with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, datetime, dataframe

I have an ascii file where the dates are formatted as follows:

```
Jan 20 2015 00:00:00.000
Jan 20 2015 00:10:00.000
Jan 20 2015 00:20:00.000
Jan 20 2015 00:30:00.000
Jan 20 2015 00:40:00.000
```

When loading the file into pandas, each column above gets its own column in a pandas dataframe. I've tried the variations of the following:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from datetime import datetime

df = read_csv('file.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True,
              parse_dates={'datetime': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
              date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d %Y %H %M %S'))
```

I get a couple errors:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
ValueError: time data 'Jun 29 2017 00:35:00.000' does not match format '%b %d %Y %H %M %S'
```

I'm confused because:

1. I'm passing a dict to `parse_dates` to parse the different columns as a single date.
2. I'm using: `%b` - abbreviated month name, `%d` - day of the month, `%Y` year with century, `%H` 24-hour, `%M` - minute, and `%S` - second

Anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly?

**Edit:**

I've tried `date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')` which returns `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000`

**Edit 2:**

I tried what @MaxU suggested in his update, but it was problematic because my original data is formatted like the following:

```
Jan   1  2017  00:00:00.000   123 456 789 111 222 333
```

I'm only interested in the first 7 columns so I import my file with the following:

```
df = read_csv(fn, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Then to create a column with datetime information from the first 4 columns I try:

```
df['datetime'] = to_datetime(df.ix[:, :3], format='%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

However this doesn't work because `to_datetime` expects "integer, float, string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series" as the first argument and `df.ix[:, :3]` returns a dataframe with the following format:

```
         0   1     2             3
0      Jan   1  2017  00:00:00.000
```

How do I feed in every row of the first four columns to `to_datetime` such that I get one column of `datetimes`?

**Edit 3:**

I think I solved my second problem. 
I just use to following command and do everything when I read my file in (I was basically just missing `%f` to parse past seconds):

```
df = read_csv(fileName, header=None, delim_whitespace=True,
              parse_dates={'datetime': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
              date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f'),
              usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

The whole reason I wanted to parse manually instead of letting pandas handle it like @MaxU suggested was to see if manually feeding in instructions would be faster - and it is! From my tests the snippet above runs approximately 5-6 times faster than letting pandas infer parsing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas (tested with version 0.20.1) is smart enough to do it for you:

```
In [4]: pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\s+', parse_dates={'datetime': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
Out[4]:
             datetime
0 2015-01-20 00:10:00
1 2015-01-20 00:20:00
2 2015-01-20 00:30:00
3 2015-01-20 00:40:00
```

**UPDATE:** if all entries have the same format you can try to do it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='~', names=['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a go to this simpler approach:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.txt')
df.columns = ['date']
```

`df` should be a dataframe with a single column. After that try casting that column to datetime

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```